# implement Tab host Using ImageViews

Tags: android, imageview

i have three imageViews.when i press that one image view i set  to change the image.
(**Clickable image,non click able image.**).when i go for another image i want to set image to clickable image.and the  imageView i have pressed , should comes to non clickable image.(**Just like a Tabhost-im doing is im developing tab using imageviews** ) are there any way to do it please .here i have attrached code snippt please find below.it

```
 loginbtn.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent arg1) {


                    switch (arg1.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                        ((ImageView)v).setImageResource(R.drawable.login_click);

                        newFragment=new Login(); 
                        FragmentTransaction transaction=getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        transaction.replace(R.id.myFragement,newFragment);
                        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                        transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                        transaction.commit();


                    }
                    return true;



                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do

int clicked = 0 ;

```
images.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

 @Override
 public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
   switch (MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(motionEvent)) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    clicked++;
                    break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                    if(clicked == 1){
                        images.setImageResource(R.drawable.click_image);
                    }else if(clicked == 2){
                        images.setImageResource(R.drawable.non_click_image);

                    return true;
                   break;
      }
 }
```

}